# Excel changes cell references when no rows are retrieved from SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to put together a dashboard from an SQL database, sometimes there is no data retrieved, which is normal but this breaks the cell references.

I have 3 worksheets Dash / Data / Calculations, when I use the offset function to put the data into a scrolling list tied to a scroll bar:-

In the Dash sheet I use  *=OFFSET(Data!A2,Calculation!$C$4,0,1,1)*

Everything works fine until the query retrieves no rows (which would be normal at times), at this point I get a load of #REF! errors and the Data! reference gets changed.

I have tried making the reference absolute Data!$A$2 but this has no effect.

Any ideas on what is going on?

---

I've managed to figure it out...here is what I did

OK so not a perfect solution, but I have used the INDIRECT function.

Data retrieved into columns A & B in a table via SQL query.

Then place a grid down for the indirect function to look at in C & D, this is just text.

Then use =INDIRECT(C1) in E1 and =INDIRECT(D1) in F1

```
 |    A     |    B     |    C     |    D     |      E       |    F     
_________________________________________________________________________
1| datar1c1 | datar1c2 |   A1     |    B1    |=INDIRECT(C1) |=INDIRECT(D1)
_________________________________________________________________________
2! datar2c1 | datar2c2 |   A2     |    B2    |=INDIRECT(C2) |=INDIRECT(D2)
```

This "Indirectly" gets the values from the cells in the table and stops Excel from killing the formulae on my dashboard worksheet, I have gone down to row 200 with columns C:F as I think that will be enough.

Comment: Here's another thought. Does your query pull down NULL values, empty cells, or Blanks? This will make a difference.

Comment: Ive managed to answer my own question....but as a noob I cant post it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure it out...here is what I did

OK so not a perfect solution, but I have used the INDIRECT function.

Data retrieved into columns A & B in a table via SQL query.

Then place a grid down for the indirect function to look at in C & D, this is just text.

Then use =INDIRECT(C1) in E1 and =INDIRECT(D1) in F1

|    A     |    B     |    C     |    D     |      E       |    F

---

1| datar1c1 | datar1c2 |   A1     |    B1    |=INDIRECT(C1) |=INDIRECT(D1)

---

2! datar2c1 | datar2c2 |   A2     |    B2    |=INDIRECT(C2) |=INDIRECT(D2)
This "Indirectly" gets the values from the cells in the table and stops Excel from killing the formulae on my dashboard worksheet, I have gone down to row 200 with columns C:F as I think that will be enough.

Now the offset function used on the Dash sheet is referring to static data and the formulas are not getting #ref'd

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using ISERROR to "handle" the error locally?

Something like this might work:

```
=IF(ISERROR(Data!A2), "", OFFSET(Data!A2,Calculation!$C$4,0,1,1))
```

This basically says if Data!A2 returns an error, then don't do anything, if it doesn't, then OFFSET...

Comment: Just had a go at that but used ISBLANK instead, because it's the blank cell (or not) at Data!A2 causing the problem but it has the same effect on the formula on the Dash sheet.

Comment: Which sheet is showing the #REF! errors - Dash?  If so, try nesting it this way:  `=IF(ISERROR(OFFSET(Data!A2,Calculation!$C$4,0,1,1), "", OFFSET(Data!A2,Calculation!$C$4,0,1,1)))`

Comment: This formula says "If the attempt to OFFSET throws an error, do nothing, if not, then OFFSET." This time don't change the formula to isblank. ;)  Try as I have suggested.